# Postsharp introduce Attributes with Property Arguments

Tags: postsharp

I am trying to achieve attribute introduction like [here](http://doc.postsharp.net/##example-dataattributes) but my attributes have property arguments like: `[Foo(Bar = "Baz")]`

How do I correctly pass the arguments?  I'm not copying the attributes from something else, so I don't think I can use CustomAttributeData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set properties of your custom attributes by using `ObjectConstruction.NamedArguments` dictionary.

For example:

```
public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
{
    Type targetType = (Type) targetElement;

    var objectConstruction =
        new ObjectConstruction(typeof (MyCustomAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
    objectConstruction.NamedArguments["Bar"] = "Baz";

    var introduceAttributeAspect = new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(objectConstruction);

    yield return new AspectInstance(targetType, introduceAttributeAspect);
}
```